# Writing a javascript closure with lambdas

Tags: javascript, closures

Wanted to write a short closure using lambdas:

```
let fetch = () => {
    let page = 0;
    return () => {
        page++;
        console.log(page);
    };
}();
```

But ended up getting:

```
file.js:7:1 SyntaxError: missing ; before statement:
file.js:7:1 }();
file.js:7:1 .^
```

Can someone please explain why? As writing it like this is fine:

```
let fetch = function() {
    let page = 0;
    return () => {
        page++;
        console.log(page);
    };
}();
```

Comment: Just write `let fetch; { let page = 0; fetch = () => { console.log(++page); }; }` :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include parenthesis around the first function before you invoke it:

```js
let fetch = (() => {
  let page = 0;
  return () => {
      page++;
      console.log(page);
  };
})();

fetch()
fetch()
```